# iPhone Object Allocation, GeneralBlock-24 & GeneralBlock-48

Tags: iphone, memory-management, instruments, quartz-graphics

I have 3 memory leaks after the launch of the iPhone application. These remain constant no matter what I do in the App (no more leaks).

My Net Object Allocation keeps growing. There are two blocks in particular, GeneralBlock-24 & GeneralBlock-48.

Block-48 gets specially bad as the program is being used, taking Megabytes of memory. The Library that seems to be allocating the objects in both blocks is QuartzCore.

The App had a reference to the QuartzCore framework, but I have eliminated all references to it.

p.s.: this is all on device, not the simulator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it! When running it on the simulator with Instruments the GeneralBlocks are reported as a single GeneralBlock-0. Searching through the web it seems that there is a bug in instruments objectAlloc reporting and QuartzCore.

So I just added a Memory Monitor instrument and saw that even though my Object Allocation kept growing non-stop, my Real Memory remained flat (well, moving up/down within half a MB)

I hope it's useful info to others, I spent a day searching for GeneralBlock-24 & 48 trying to figure it out until deciding to run it in the simulator just for the heck of it